# Solve the following integro-differential equation by Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-equations

guys, I can solve this by using the convolution theorem however when it comes to Laplace I'm stuck somehow. Can someone help me with this, please?
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}+2\int_{0}^{t}y(\tau)cosh(t-\tau))d\tau = 4 + \delta (t)  \quad ;y(0)=3
$$

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. On this site, saying "I'm stuck" is not enough to guarantee a reply. You should say exactly what you have tried and where you got stuck, so someone can provide the right help for you.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+2\int_{0}^{t}y(\tau)\cosh (t-\tau))d\tau = 4 + \delta (t) \\ y(0)=3$$
Note that:
$$\mathcal{L}(\delta (t))=1 \text { and }
 \mathcal{L}(\cosh t)=\dfrac s{s^2-1}$$
Now apply the Laplace Transform:
$$sY(s)-y(0)+2Y(s)\dfrac s{s^2-1} = \dfrac 4 s + 1$$
$$sY(s)\left ( 1+\dfrac 2{s^2-1} \right ) = \dfrac 4 s + 4$$
$$Y(s)=\dfrac {4(s+1)(s^2-1)}{s^2(s^2+1)}$$
$$Y(s)=4(s+1) \left (\dfrac 2{s^2+1}-\dfrac 1{s^2} \right)$$
$$Y(s)=4\left (-\dfrac 1{s}-\dfrac 1{s^2}+\dfrac {2s}{s^2+1}+\dfrac 2{s^2+1} \right)$$
Apply inverse Laplace Transform.
$$\boxed {y(t)=4\left (-1-t+2 \cos t+2 \sin t \right)}$$

Comment: I do not get it why there is $s^2+1$ in the third equation's denominator, could you explain it, please?

Comment: Look at the table its the Laplace transform of cosh function. Third equation has $s^2-1$ at the denominator

Comment: Is it here  ? $sY(s)\left ( 1+\dfrac 2{s^2-1} \right ) = \dfrac 4 s + 4$ Then $sY(s)\left ( \dfrac {s^2+1}{s^2-1} \right ) = \dfrac 4 s + 4$  @sheldoniscute